# Music Home Sharing not visible in iOS 10

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, music, home-sharing

How do I access Home Sharing for Music in iOS10? I'd like to stream music from my Mac iTunes Library.

When I go to the *Music* app, there are no contents:

[image]

Home Sharing is active in iTunes on my Mac serving the audio. I can see the Library contents using the *Remote* app, and I can also access the Mac Library from another Mac.

Home Sharing is active on my iPhone, I'm logged into my Apple ID in my iOS *Settings > Music*.

[image]

Has this feature been removed, or is there something I'm missing here? This [Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT202190), last updated May 2016, says it should be possible in what appears to be iOS 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hadn't actually opened the Music app since I upgraded to iOS 10, but I did so to see what I could find for this question. On the main screen, I immediately have a Home Sharing option, and tapping on it goes to a screen with my computer's name. See screenshot below.

I'd suggest logging out of Home Sharing on your iPhone, waiting 15 minutes, and logging back in. Also make sure you're running the latest version of iTunes (12.1.5.21 as of this writing).

[image]

Comment: Logging out/in of Home Sharing on the Phone worked. I waited for a while before logging back in.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure computer where library is is not sleeping or home sharing option does not seem to appear on IOS device.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review